# What is the most appropriate derivative free optimization algorithm

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

We can use [random optimization/ derivative free/ direct search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_optimization) to find the minimum of some black box function $f$.

If I have some 2D black box function, $f(x,y)$ - which I know to be convex -  what is the best derivative-free method to use?

i.e. from a speed perspective is it best to use e.g. [Nelder-Mead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method), [Compass/Pattern search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_search_(optimization)), [MADS](https://www.gerad.ca/~charlesa/PUB/mads2004jopt.pdf) etc?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could define "appropriate". I assume you are looking for the highest-performance solution? How expensive is it to compute $f(x,y)$, say, relative to $exp(x)$? Is the computing platform highly parallel (e.g. a GPU)?

Answer (score 8):

As the "*No Free Lunch Theorems for Search*" [[1](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.33.5447)] states that **there is no one particular optimization algorithm that works best for every problem**, i.e., citing the authors:

> all algorithms that search for an extremum of a cost
>   function perform exactly the same, when averaged over all possible
>   cost functions. In particular, if algorithm A outperforms algorithm B
>   on some cost functions, then loosely speaking there must exist exactly
>   as many other functions where B outperforms A.

However, for a really good guidance, I would suggest to look at the recent article [[2](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10898-012-9951-y)] (*written by two well-known optimizers*), which presents a review and comparison of 22 derivative-free algorithms performed on a test set consisting of 502  **convex/nonconvex**, **smooth/nonsmooth** optimization problems.

### References

1: [Wolpert, D. H., & Macready, W. G. (1995). No free lunch theorems for search (Vol. 10). Technical Report SFI-TR-95-02-010, Santa Fe Institute.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.33.5447)

2: [Rios, L. M., & Sahinidis, N. V. (2013). Derivative-free optimization: a review of algorithms and comparison of software implementations. Journal of Global Optimization, 56(3), 1247-1293.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10898-012-9951-y)

Comment: Well I cannot view the paper myself, but I would question the statement "all algorithms that search for an extremum of a cost function perform exactly the same, when averaged over all possible cost functions".  Do the authors _prove_ that statement?  The reason I ask, is that I recently implemented a "pure random" optimizer that basically "flings numerical faeces at the wall" and keeps track of the best solution.  Needless to say, it was (empirically) equally awful at any function that I tried it on!  I would be interested to learn what "class" of cost functions it is best suited to ;)

Answer (score 2):

As @Remis says, it's very problem-dependent. I think the best thing to do is use a nice package with a suite of methods and just test them all. [NLopt.jl](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/NLopt.jl) makes it easy to try [quite a large number of algorithms](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_Algorithms/) (including a lot of derivative-free methods). The one that's best for your problem is the one that performs best.

Comment: I got a glimpse of what Julia has to offer for numerical ODEs (thanks to some of your previous posts), and I must say I'm positively impressed. does Julia offer other functionality similar to that of Python's `numpy`/`scipy`? if so, could you point me to some good reference material that can get me started with the language?

Comment: Python's `numpy` equivalent is just Julia's base library. See how it's all covered in [the manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/). For what SciPy offers, Julia offers the same stuff but through a confederation of packages (much like R). A good source to search through packages is [JuliaObserver](https://juliaobserver.com/packages), for example you can find Optim.jl and JuMP near the top for optimization. The language is still relatively new (with 1.0 coming this summer) but has a lot of unique packages already.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar question, and in general it is tough in Python world because choosing a derivative-free optimizer requires one to compare scipy.optimize, dlib, ax-platform, hyperopt, nevergrad, optuna, bayesopt, platypus, pymoo, pySOT and skopt (and more by the time you read this) and there is barely a convention in common.

I finally decided I would just do it once and for all. So now I compute Elo ratings for 60+ derivative free optimizers, as explained in a blog article [HumpDay: A Package to Help You Choose a Python Global Optimizer](https://www.microprediction.com/blog/humpday). You can also put your objective function directly into a colab [notebook](https://github.com/microprediction/humpday/blob/main/humpday_points_race.ipynb) and it will show you which package does the best job.

I won't presume to know which will work in your case, but don't overlook the following:  dlib, pySOT (dycors); skopt; nevergrad (ngopt8); shgo. Ping me if you'd like to add your objective function to the test suite. I do have a sneaking suspicion that an Algorithm from the 1960s is going to work just fine in your case.

btw if you go with Julia instead, more power to you!